I'm looking for an old manga where the protagonist manipulates space and time
The manga begins with a presentation of the world where people awaken magical powers and after that we see the protagonist suffering bullying for not awakening until he fights back, thus awakening his power of time and space, of course he soon loses consciousness.
(I read this manga when mangalivre was alive around 2016-2018, I don't remember the date specifically. The manga's cover was colorful and had a black-haired boy with one eye with a black background and a green pupil.)

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

it is entirely colorful
